# Safe to serialize class instantiation and store in file_put_contents?

Tags: php, oop, serialization

I am trying to find the best/safest way to carry my class instantiation throughout all files in my project. Currently I am using the following method. Is this safe? Should I be storing it in the $_SESSION? Any guidance would be much appreciated! Ty!

```
(./classes/test-class.php)
class MyTestClass {
  private $name; 
  function __construct($newName){
    $this->name = $newName;
  }
  public function get_name(){
    return $this->name;
  }
}


(index.php)
require_once('./classes/test-class.php');
$user = new MyTestClass("Bob");
$s = serialize( $user );
file_put_contents('store-obj.php', $s);


(user-profile.php)
require_once('./classes/test-class.php');
$s = file_get_contents('store-obj.php');
$user = unserialize($s);
echo $user->get_name(); // Returns "Bob"
```

Comment: depending on the purpose of `$user`, I believe you should store it in `$_SESSION`, besides php files are programming files not just ordinary text files or data files, if you absolutely need to store it(maybe you want the info across sessions) store it in an ordinary file , array,etc

Answer (score 0):

If the class just contains ordinary data (strings, numbers, arrays, other objects), serializing and saving it in a file is fine.

If it contains any dynamic information related to external entities (such as databases and network connections) you need to define the [`__sleep()` and `__wakeup()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) magic methods to clean this up when serializing and reinstate it when unserializing.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what kind of feature you're trying to implement. Persisting a serialized instance in a file to share the object between requests will work, yes. Also you could store it in a database. (And be aware of Barmar hint to `__sleep()` and `__wakeup`). But in most cases the standard approach would be to newly instantiate your object with every new request.

And your filesnames `index.php` and `user-profile.php` make me suspect you're dealing with user content. With your proposed solution you'll load the same instance for every requests (regardless of the user that made the request). If you're dealing with some kind of a user-object, thats probably not what you want. In that case you should use $_SESSION as storage.